# IntelliJ add existing project to existing Git repository in specific directory

Tags: github, intellij-idea, version-control

I am working on a project that involves some source code for an embedded system as well as a java program written in IntelliJ to interact with my hardware (6 java source files and 1 jar dependency). I want all of these (including some other files) to be in one git repository but in different directories e.g. Arduino code, IntelliJ project, and other files all in different directories of the same repository. While most of the files, I will handle manually using the command line, I want my IntelliJ project to use the built-in version control feature.
I already have the git repository with the directory structure as I want to use it. The java program which I have developed in IntelliJ is also already existing, but only on my local machine.
How do I get my IntelliJ project into the specific directory of the git repository while also being able to use the IntelliJ VCS features?

Sorry for this long-winded question... If I have left out some vital information, let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: look at this tutorial-video: [https://youtu.be/mf2-MOl0VXY](https://youtu.be/mf2-MOl0VXY) that's how it worked for me.

Comment: This is almost what I need. But the difference being that this solution pushes all the committed files into the root directory of the repository. I need them to be inside a specific folder that is in the root directory.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you would like your Intellij project in an existing Git repo and there in a specific directory ?

Comment: @Custos Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your issue:
" I want all of these (including some other files) to be in one git repository but in different directories e.g. Arduino code, IntelliJ project, and other files all in different directories"

You need to have a directory structure like

```
myProject/
├── .git
├── ArduinoCode
├── JavaCode
└── someFolder
```

So it means that you need to "git init" in a folder of your project.

Speaking of IntelliJ Version Control System - once the project is opened you should be able to see "Git" tool window at the bottom part of a window.
If not, please go to **Preferences | Version Control** and check whether you see directory with git initialized in a list.